# The $n$-th derivative of $(x-c)^k$ (a compact formulation?)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, derivatives

As part of our calculations, we are trying to compute the $n$-th derivative of $(x-c)^k$ for $0<x<c$, $c>0$ and any positive integer $k$.

From what *K.K.McDonald* proposed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4341956/closed-form-expression-of-the-n-th-derivative-of-f-kx-e-cxcx-u-xk), I think maybe we can write it as a series but it makes future analysis extremely complicated.

Is it possible to have a more compact and "easy-to-handle" formulation for the higher order derivatives of $(x-c)^k$?

**EDIT**

I think I should have mentioned this before.

We are trying to compute the $n$-th derivative of
$$f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k(x-c)^k.$$

So we wrote
$$f^{(n)}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k\frac{d^n}{dx^n}[(x-c)^k],$$
and got stuck!

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%5En%2Fdx%5En+%28x-c%29%5Ek

Comment: Am I missing something? Isn't it $k\cdot (k-1) \cdot ...  \cdot (k-n+1)(x-c)^{k-n}$?

Comment: I used Maxima to calculate the 10th derivate of $(x-c)^{k}$ and got $\left( k-9\right) \, \left( k-8\right) \, \left( k-7\right) \, \left( k-6\right) \, \left( k-5\right) \, \left( k-4\right) \, \left( k-3\right) \, \left( k-2\right) \, \left( k-1\right)  k {{\left( x-c\right) }^{k-10}}$. Can you recognize the pattern?

Comment: As the Wolframalpha link suggests, you should look up the falling factorial for the most compact representation (that still uses known notation).

Comment: @AlvaroMartinez If $n>k$, it should be zero no?

Comment: @RadialArmSaw Thank you. For our problem, I think the answers of "banlieu XY" and "miracle173" are more compact. I asked a question to better understand what happens when $n>k$. You can see a thorough answer from "Paul Sinclair" [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4350041/understanding-sum-n-0m-sum-k-1-infty-m-choose-ngm-nx-a-k-fra)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part of this question should actually be the following: Why can we exchange the differentiation $\frac{d}{dx}$ and the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$. There is a theorem in calculus which states that you can do this for $x$ inside the radius of convergence, namely if the radius of convergence of $(a_k)_k$ is $R>0$,
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k(x-c)^k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k  \frac{d}{dx}  (x-c)^k\quad  \forall x:|x-c|<R. $$
This can be repeated for finitely many times (by induction) so that we can solve your problem with the $n$-th derivative. We find for $x$ with $|x-c|<R$
$$f^{(n)}(x) =  \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k(x-c)^k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)^n (x-c)^k = \sum_{k=n}^\infty a_k \frac{k!}{(k-n)!}(x-c)^{k-n}.$$

Also have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Radius_of_convergence.

Comment: You should divide by $(k-n)!$ in the end and not $(n-k)!$. Also you can start the summation at $k=n$.

Comment: Of course! I corrected it. I can still start at $k=1$ in the second last sum because the derivative is 0 so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

So $$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x-c)^k=\frac{k!}{(k-n)!}(y-c)^{k-n}$$
if $n\le k$, which can easily confimed by induction.

It is $0$ if $n>k$.

Comment: Thank you. This formulation holds only for $n\leq k$. If $n>k$, the derivative should be zero so I'm confused about the formulation you proposed.

Comment: yes, you are right, I edited the post.

Comment: Thank you. So if $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_k(x-c)^k$, can we have a closed-form expression for $f^{(n)}(x)$?

Comment: @zoogoo:  if you allow binomial coefficients as "closed forms", then you could write it as $n! {k \choose n}$.  Under the usual definitions of binomial coefficients, this automatically vanishes when $n>k$.

Comment: @zoogoo You define $f$ as a series (with arbitrary coefficients), so you can’t hope to get a closed form for $f^{(n)}$, when $f$ doesn’t even have one.

Answer (score -1):

If $$f(x) = \sum_{k \geq 0} a_k (x-c)^k$$ (so in your case, $a_0 = 0$, this is a bit more general, but if you're taking derivatives, it doesn't really matter), we have $$f'(x) = \sum_{k \geq 1}  k a_k (x-c)^{k-1},$$ the term with just $a_0$ we can throw out, similarly $$f''(x) = \sum_{k \geq 2}  k (k-1) a_k (x-c)^{k-2}.$$ Again, the first term with $a_1 \times 1$ becomes zero so we throw it away. In general, by following the pattern, we suspect $$f^{(n)} (x) = \sum_{k \geq n} k (k-1) \cdots (k - (n-1)) a_k (x-c)^{k-n},$$ and this is true. One would usually prove this by induction.